# URL Rewrite http to https with www

Tags: .htaccess, rewrite, httpd.conf

I have a domain with several apps.  All apps should be reached like this.

https://www.website.com/app1/
https://www.website.com/app2/
https://www.website.com/app3/

The problem I'm having is with my url rewrites.  If someone enters  website.com/app1/ or www.website.com/app1/  I want it to rewrite to this  https://www.website.com/app1/

I've been attempting to use httpd.conf to solve this problem or just .htaccess in the document root folder without any luck.  URL rewrite works fine in my codeignighter application, just not in these one off stand alone apps.

Can anyone show me the proper way to incorporate url rewrites to solve the above problem?

Answer (score 0):

Now open httpd.conf or .htaccess file (mod_rewrite not required):

```
 # vi httpd.conf
```

Append following line :

```
  Redirect permanent /app1 https://www.website.com/app1
```

Any request made to http://www.website.com/app1 will goto https://www.website.com/app1

Save and close the file. Restart the Apache:

```
  # /etc/init.d/httpd restart
```

Comment: Hi,

Your solution works if I enter www.website.com/app1

If I enter website.com/app1 (without www. preceding) it doesn't work.

Comment: both are same..

Comment: I edited my comment.